# WebRTC: Modify Bandwidth Parameters of SDP

Tags: javascript, webrtc

when initializing / renegotiating a call, and creating offer/answer sdp using PeerConnection's `createOffer`/`createAnswer`, before setting the sdp using, `setLocalDescription`, I modify it as:

```
    // inside createOffer/createAnswer
    sdp.sdp = modifySDP(sdp.sdp);
    pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, function...

...
// setting video bandwidth as 100kbps and audio as 50kbps.
function modifySDP(sdp){        
    sdp = sdp.replace(/a=mid:video\r\n/g, 'a=mid:video\r\nb=AS:100\r\n');        
    sdp = sdp.replace(/a=mid:audio\r\n/g, 'a=mid:audio\r\nb=AS:50\r\n');
    return sdp;
}
```

After few tests, I realized that firefox does not support this modification, already reported as [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=976521)

But what suprised me was, chrome behaviour. Initially because I was setting bandwidth restrictions on both sides, so I did not notice this( later I applied the restrictions only on the offerer's side). My assumption was that that, when you set SDP on a PeerConnection, the restrictions apply to the **outgoing streams**, but what I noticed was, the restrictions got applied to the **incoming streams**. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: I always believe that those bandwidth parameters means that the total stream cannot exceed that bandwidth. It seems to force/imply a network limitation on that particular peer with what they can send and receive. Whether this is the intent or not, I am not sure.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent, when I did the tests, I was continuously monitoring the webrtc stats in chrome, whenever I reduce the bandwidth in peer1 from 1000 kbps(normal value) to 200kbps, (stats) I find that peer2's encoding bitrate hovers around 200kbps, peer's bitrate remains unchanged. Also I am able to see a clear reduction in the quality of video provided by peer2 to peer1(, again no change for peer1).

Comment: Interesting stuff. This may be a question or a bug for the chromium bug tracker. They could at least tell you its by design if it is not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior and this is what I get when I use a bandwidth limitation:

> If the bandwidth attribute is present for a stream in the sdp offer, it indicates the desired bandwidth that the offerer would like to receive.
>
> The answerer MAY include a bandwidth attribute for any media stream;
>      this indicates the bandwidth that the answerer would like the offerer
>      to use when sending media.

So what you've got is the expected behavior.